# Reusing code: friend methods with non-friend methods

Tags: c++, templates, code-reuse

I was wondering which is it's possible to re-use code for `methods` that have a corresponding `friend` version? For instance, in the example given below, both `doSomething` and `initDoSomething` methods do the same computations and therefore their implementation is practically the same. Which would be the best way to do such a thing so as to re-use code?

```
template < typename T >
class CFoo;

template < typename T > CFoo<T> doSomething( double );

template < typename T >
class CFoo{
    public:
        ...
        friend CFoo<T> doSomething< >( double );
        CFoo<T> initDoSomething( double );
};
```

Any suggestions are welcomed ;-)

What I would like to achieve is something like:
`myFooObject1 = doSomething(3.0);` without needing to necessarily initialize an object or also:
`myFooObject1.doSomething(3.0);`

Comment: Whe do you need both version? Don't you need to make initDoSomething a static function instead?

Comment: Does initDoSomething() access members from CFoo? If yes, how can it do the same thing as doSomething()? If not, why is it a member?

Comment: In my humble opinion friends and templates should be avoided. Only use them if necessary and they make logical sense. Why, exactly, are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I updated my original post explaining what I would like to achieve.

Comment: I would suggest you go away and thing of the difference between functional programming and object oriented programming, Also look up the word `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if a function needs to access the private data-members of a class, you should make it a method of the class rather than a friend-function.  There are specific instances where you may want to have a friend function, such as with and overloaded version of `operator>>`, etc., in order to create a common interface between your objects and other standard C++ interfaces such as streams.  Another common use of a stand-alone friend function would be for creating a single function interface that will be parameterized in some way, but  you want to keep the interface for that function the same (i.e., a single template-function may take multiple different class types, but you want to call that function the same way with any instantiated version).  In general though, making functions as friends of a class just so they can access the private data members of a class breaks the entire idea of data encapsulation that classes create for their private data members in the first place.

In your case, you haven't explicitly explained why `doSomething` has to be a friend and not a method ... as it stands right now, with the function declaration, there doesn't seem to be any reason why it can't be a public method of `CFoo`.  Secondly, if you are trying to initialize a global-state for your `doSomething` function, you will want to make `initDoSomething` a static function of the class rather than a method, so that every version of `CFoo<T>` is initialized for a call to `doSomething` rather than just a single instance of `CFoo<T>`.  As it stands right now, you would have to initialize every instance of `CFoo<T>` before it can be used with `doSomething`.  Semantically that doesn't make sense since `doSomething` creates a `CFoo<T>` instance before you can call `initDoSomething` on that instance to initialize it for a call to `doSomething`.

Comment: I updated my original post illustrating what I would like to achieve.

Comment: It sounds to me like you basically want a factory function ... This begins the question, what is the purpose of `initDoSomething`? Is it simply a "generator" function that `doSomething` calls in order to create a `CFoo<T>` object?  If so, it needs to be `static`, since again, you can't call a method on an object that hasn't already been constructed unless you are doing so in the constructor itself (i.e., via the `this` pointer) ... Also if this is what you're wanting, then there is no need for `doSomething` to be a friend-function, since `initDoSomething` is declared as `public`.

Comment: "_if a function needs to access the private data-members of a class, you should make it a method of the class rather than a friend-function._" Why?

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve code-reuse in C++ is to simply factor common code into (possibly parametrized) shared functions.

In your case, I assume that `initDoSomething` accesses to private members (otherwise, why is it a member function?). So chances are that in your case your shared function takes two arguments and `initDoSomething` calls it passing the private member(s) as arguments to the shared function.

Comment: do you mind giving an illustration your answer? I also updated my original post illustrating what I would like to achieve.

Comment: "_I assume that initDoSomething accesses to private members (otherwise, why is it a member function?)._" Why a member? because the author think it belongs here, obviously.

Comment: @curiousguy: Right, but *why* does the author think it belongs there? You should make functions members only if necessary, not if possible.

Comment: You mean that functions should be friend rather than members? Makes sense.

Comment: @curiousguy: No; I mean that the shared code should be put into functions which get the required values (say, private member variables) via arguments. That way, these functions can't access *all* private state of an object (which a friend function can).